# C in 2048,problems with moving

Tags: c, stdin, 2048

I am making 2048 game in C and I need help. Moves are made by pressing <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> keys e.g. <kbd>W</kbd> is for moving up, <kbd>S</kbd> for down.

However, after every letter you have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept it. How can I make it work without pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>?

Comment: How do you listen user's inputs? stdin?

Comment: use an infinite loop in which u keep calling a function named if(kbhit()) and if it returns true you can use getch to get the input without echo

Comment: [fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) is your friend

Answer (score 2):

what you are asking for is function named kbhit() which returns true if user presses a key on the keyboard. you can use this function to get input from the use too like see

```
char c= ' ';
while(1){
    if(kbhit())
        c=getch();
    if(c=='q')// condition to stop the infinite loop 
        break;
}
```

Comment: C standard mentions no `kbhit()` function. You are using some compiler specific library function.

Comment: my bro it is a function defined in conio.h [link](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/kbhit)

Comment: @AliAkberFaiz `conio.h` is a non-standard-header. It is a windows only header file which makes you answer only useful if the OP uses a windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard library function in c to accomplish this; instead you will have to use termios functions to gain control over the terminal and then reset it back after reading the input.

I came across some code to read input from stdin without waiting for a delimiter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547868/is-there-a-way-to-get-user-input-without-pressing-the-enter-key).

If you are on linux and using a standard c compiler then getch() will not be easily available for you. Hence i have implemented the code in the link and you just need to paste this code and use the getch() function normally.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  new = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

int main()
{
    int ch;

    ch = getch();//just use this wherever you want to take the input

    printf("%d", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as Ali's solution is only valid for Windows, this solution is only valid for Unix (and Linux).